Calculating Correction Bytes for my QR-Code
i am making a QR-Code generator and are now at the last step. All i need to do now is to calculate the Correctionbytes in order the scanner to read my QR-Code.
https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/error-correction-coding#step-9-divide-the-message-polynomial-by-the-generator-polynomial
This Link shows how to calculate Correctionbytes and is what i am using as a reference to implement it in my Code.
My Problem is that i tried to Follow the same step and instruction  but dont get the right result.
Here is my Code to Calculate the Correctionbytes. My Function recieved two Arrays.
The messagePolynomial array possess the Context of the QR-Code where every character is in ASCII-Code. The generator Array has the generator polynomial. What i have to do is through polynomial division get The Correctionbytes. the link above will explain it in Detail.
Right now i am Working on a Prototype with a fix size and length.
Qr-Code size is 21 x 21 a version 1 with a correctionlevel L (Low) which means that i need 7 correctionbytes in order for my QR-Code to Funktion.
My generatorpolynomial look like this [0, 87, 229, 146, 149, 238, 102, 21];
My messagepolynomial look like this [226, 72, 250, 250, 61, 5, 43, 61, 155, 250, 195, 138]
The values shown are in Alphanotation.


private int[] CalculateCorrectionBytes(int[] messagePolynomial, int[] generator)
{
    int[] log = buildLog(buildAntiLog());
    int[] antilog = buildAntiLog();
    int[] correctionBytes = new int[generator.Length];

    int[] message = (int[])messagePolynomial.Clone();

    Console.WriteLine($"Generator polynomial in Alpha notation: [{string.Join(", ", generator)}]\n");

    
    for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine($"{i}. Message character as integer: {message[i]}");
        message[i] = log[message[i]];
        Console.WriteLine($"{i}. Message character in Alpha notation: {message[i]}");
        Console.WriteLine("________________________________");
    }

    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int leadTerm = message[0];
        Console.WriteLine($"\n>>>>>  {i + 1}. Calculation step!  <<<<<\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < generator.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\n*****************************> {j + 1}. generator term <*****************************************");
            int logvalue = (leadTerm + generator[j]) % 255;
            Console.WriteLine($"The log value is {logvalue} when {leadTerm} plus {generator[j]} is calculated " +
                              $"and then modulo 255 is taken." +
                              $"---> {logvalue} = {leadTerm} + {generator[j]}");
            
            int antilogvalue = antilog[logvalue];
            Console.WriteLine($"The value of {logvalue} in AntiLog is {antilogvalue}");

            int xorvalue = antilog[message[j]] ^ antilogvalue;
            Console.WriteLine($"When {antilog[message[j]]} XOR {antilogvalue} ---> {antilog[message[j]]} XOR {antilogvalue} = {xorvalue}");
            
            Console.WriteLine($"The value {xorvalue} takes the place of message[{j}]({message[j]}).");
            message[j] = xorvalue;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"message array after step {i + 1}: [{string.Join(", ", message)}]");
        // Remove the leading coefficient after it has been processed
        message = message.Skip(1).ToArray();

        // Output the new "reduced" temp[] array
        Console.WriteLine($"New message array after reduction {i + 1}: [{string.Join(", ", message)}]");
    }
    
    correctionBytes = (int[])message.Clone();
    Console.WriteLine($"Correction bytes after calculation: [{string.Join(", ", correctionBytes)}]\n");

    return correctionBytes;
}

When i run my Values through my Code i get these values as Correctionbytes [146, 177, 89, 225, 238, 87, 248].
The thing is i have use Thonkys QR-Code Generator to see if the Qr-Code i generate is identical. With the exception of the correctionbytes everything seems correct. So can someone help me?

Please refer to [mcve]. If you need help to fix the code, then someone needs to be able to run it, see wrong results, fix code and see correct results.

Each element of the message is a value, while each element of the generator polynomial is log[value], which makes the code awkward. How does the code handle log[0], which could be in the message or the result of a calculation? It would be simpler to always use values and only use log[] for multiply (after checking for either value == 0). Multiply could also use a 64KB table; multiply(a,b) = table[(a<<256)+b] without any log.

The format is 19 bytes of data and 7 bytes of "correction" (parity). This prior answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46615870/3282056 .

@rcgldr finally got it thanks for the help
